# Get The Latest Records from Table 2 with a twist

Tags: sql, sql-server

So I have 2 tables . MobileRequest and MobileRequestAnswers.

Format of tables like so :

**Table 1 - Mobile Request**

```
ID  Job_Number  MobileRequestID     CreatedOn

1   12          23                  1-March-2017
2   12          25                  1-Dec-2017
3   13          57                  1-Jan-2016
```

**Table 2 - Mobile Request Answers**

```
ID  ResourceID  MobileRequestID     QuestionID  Answer

1   10          23                  1           Space R
2   10          23                  2           Boston
3   10          23                  4           Good
4   10          25                  2           New York
5   10          25                  1           Space D
6   10          25                  5           Jimmy
7   12          57                  3           Bobby
```

What I need to find is find the most recent MobileRequests ( Table 1) for a job number, that does not have question id 4 in the set of records from  MobileRequestAnswers ( Table 2), as long as it is the most recent mobile request and has other records in Table for that mobile request id for other questions. The join between the tables is MobileRequestID.

**Example 1** 
So for instance for Job Number 12 , I should receive no mobile request ID back as mobile request id 25 has a question id 4 in the 1st set of records returned in Table 2.

**Example 2**
For Job Number 13, I should get Mobile Request ID 57.

Tried a few combos of self joins but cant get the result I expect yet, so any steer would be appreciated.

Comment: I can't understand what are you trying to say, mybe a desired outputs will be better :)

Comment: What have you tried so far??????????????  SO is not a free coding service.

Comment: @Eric - Looking through most other questions, I think that SO really ***is*** a free coding service ;)

Comment: In example one do you mean mobile request id 23 instead of 25

Comment: If `id = 3` didn't exist in table 2, what should the result be for `job_number = 12`?  Is `MobileRequestID, QuestionID` unique, or can the same `MobileQuestionID` have the same `QuetionID` multiple times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing if there is a `job` table, I would start with something like the following to get only the jobs that have no question 4 associated to them in `mobile_request_answers`.

```
WITH
    jobs_checked_question_4 AS
(
    SELECT
        mr.*,
        MAX(
            CASE WHEN mra.QuestionID = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
           )
               OVER (PARTITION BY mr.job_number)   AS HasQuestionID4,
        RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY mr.job_number
                         ORDER BY mr.CreatedOn )   AS RequestRank
    FROM
        mobile_request            AS mr
    LEFT JOIN
        mobile_request_answer     AS mra
            ON  mra.MobileRequestID = mr.MobileRequestID
)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    jobs_checked_question_4
WHERE
        HasQuestionID4 = 0     -- The job never associates to a QuestionID 4
    AND RequestRank    = 1     -- The most recent Request for each Job
```

Will return all the `answer` records for the most recent `request` for each `job`, provided that the `job` has no `request` records that associated to an `answer` with `QuestionID = 4`

Can return multiple requests for the same job if those requests were created on the same date.

Comment: `AND Request_Rank = 1` instead of `AND Rquest_Rank = 1` and correct the `job_number` you are writing `jobnumber` in the `MAX()` function

Comment: @Sami - Please don't edit my answer.  I'm editing it too.

Comment: Spot on in terms of what I was looking and the way you did it was brilliant. Thank you.